# I face a problem in SQL: "could not be a bound"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I face a problem in SQL Server with a command which shows the error "Could not be a bound".

```
select 
    part.date as Partial_date, part.location as partial_Location
union
select 
    fully.date as full_date, fully.location as full_Location, 
    people_vaccinated, people_fully_vaccinated  
from
    dbo.Partial_vaccinated part
full outer join 
    dbo.full_vaccinated fully on part.date = fully.date 
                              and part.location = fully.location
```

It shows error at `part.date` and `part.location`.

Can anyone solve this?

Here I need to put a union between two-column of different tables which already contain outer join

Table #1

```
Date        location    vaccinated  
----------------------------------
2021-05-14  Turkey      14814316
2021-05-14  Ukraine       936497
2021-05-15  Finland      2105016
```

Table #2

```
Date       location  fully_vaccinated
-------------------------------------
2021-05-14 Turkey         2941
2021-05-15 Qatar        824293
```

Desired output:

```
Date        location   vaccinated     fully_vaccinated
---------------------------------------------------------
2021-05-14  Turkey      14814316            2941
2021-05-14  Ukraine      936497             NULL
2021-05-15  Qatar       NULL              824293
2021-05-15  Finland      2105016            NULL
```

Comment: Each query in your union has to be a complete query. Here you first query isn't selecting from a table. And each query is independent, so you can't reference columns in your first query which are defined in your second query. You need to write 2 stand-alone queries which work by themselves, and then union them.

Comment: And please ensure you always post your complete error verbatim. Don't summarise it, or write it in your own words.

Comment: could you make it which hold both tables dates one column and locations in one column and  people_vaccinated, people_fully_vaccinated if exist on that date and location then show it otherwise null

Comment: I put minimal of the table as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Gordon was first with the same answer (full outer join - not union), so accept his. I've added mine to show you how to add a minimal reproducible example in future when you ask questions (since I've spent the time typing it in).

```
create table #Partial_Vaccinated (
  [Date] date
  , [Location] varchar(32)
  , People_Vaccinated int
)

create table #Full_Vaccinated (
  [Date] date
  , [Location] varchar(32)
  , People_Fully_Vaccinated int
)

insert into #Partial_Vaccinated ([Date], [Location], People_Vaccinated)
values
('2021-05-14',  'Turkey',  14814316),
('2021-05-14',  'Ukraine', 936497),
('2021-05-15',  'Finland', 2105016);

insert into #Full_Vaccinated ([Date], [Location], People_Fully_Vaccinated)
values
('2021-05-14', 'Turkey',  2941),
('2021-05-15', 'Qatar',   824293);

select
  coalesce(PV.[Date],FV.[Date]) as [Date]
  , coalesce(PV.[Location],FV.[Location]) as [Location]
  , People_Vaccinated Partially_Vaccinated
  , People_Fully_Vaccinated as Fully_Vaccinated
from #Partial_Vaccinated PV
full outer join #Full_Vaccinated FV on PV.[Date] = FV.[Date] and PV.[Location] = FV.[Location]
order by [Location];
```

Returns:

| Date | Location | Partially_Vaccinated | Fully_Vaccinated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-15 | Finland | 2105016 | NULL |
| 2021-05-15 | Qatar | NULL | 824293 |
| 2021-05-14 | Turkey | 14814316 | 2941 |
| 2021-05-14 | Ukraine | 936497 | NULL |

Note: Personally I would change the table design and have a single table with a bit column for full or partial.

Also you want to keep your aliases as short as possible while still being meaningful in the context of the query. I suggest 1-2 chars where possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `coalesce()` with `full join`:

```
select coalesce(part.date, fully.date )as date,
       coalesce(part.location, fully.location) as location, 
       part.people_vaccinated, fully.people_fully_vaccinated  
from dbo.Partial_vaccinated part full outer join
     dbo.full_vaccinated fully
     on part.date = fully.date and part.location = fully.location
```